# What do you call tags that need no ending tag?

Tags: html, terminology

There are HTML tags, such as `<img />`, `<input />` and `<button />`, that need no ending tag (`</img>`, `</input>` and `</button>`). What is the term that describes this type of tags?

Comment: None of <img />, <input /> or <button /> are HTML tags. They're XHTML tags. HTML tags never have a / before the closing >. *Never*.

Comment: @Tom Anderson: even worse: depending on context, this *is* actually valid HTML syntax, but it doesn't mean what people generally think it means.

Comment: In HTML, it gets treated as another attribute named "/", hence the reason why the space is necessary in XHTML, it's for compatibility reasons. In XML, there need not be a space before the closing forward slash.

Comment: @Tom Anderson. Yes they do - in HTML5 the '/' is optional but valid for void elements. img and input are void so the '/' is valid there. button is not a void element so it isn't valid. Furthermore, on svg and mathml elements the '/' causes the element to be self closing like XML. See http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/syntax.html#start-tags

Comment: @Turnor - That '/' gets treated as an attribute is a myth. Can you name any browser's parser that creates an attribute called '/' in the DOM when it encounters a '/' character in the html?

Comment: @Alohci: i'd forgotten about HTML5, my mistake. Amend 'HTML' to read 'HTML of versions prior to 5' :).

Comment: @Jörg: ah yes, the infamous SGML null end tag. In theory, yes, you could use it in HTML, and indeed, it means something completely unexpected. But there has never been an SGML-based web browser, so as far as i know, it's never *actually* been possible in HTML.

Comment: @Tom Anderson: Yes, but there are many SGML-based HTML validators, which can lead to many a wasted hour of staring at markup, staring at Firebug and staring at validator messages and wondering WTF there are three completely different interpretations of the same friggin' document :-)

Comment: @Alohci: You have to remember that browsers aren't necessarily the only programs to deal with HTML parsing, the requirement for adding a space before the closing slash was for any systems that might interpret it as part of the attribute otherwise, as the HTML spec allows.

Comment: @Turnor. Ah right. That's different from what you said before though. It's true that the '/' could be part of an unquoted attribute value, and that adding a space would stop that, but there's nothing in any HTML spec that then indicate that it would form the next attribute name. The SGML Null End Tag requirements would prohibit that.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This syntax has a variety of names depending on what language you are using. The best way to find out what it is called is to look at the specification for the specific language.

**HTML 4.x**

I can't find any mention of this syntax in the HTML 4.x specification. It is not valid syntax.

**HTML 5**

In the HTML 5 specification the `/` character (called a SOLIDUS) is valid but has no effect for [void elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/syntax.html#void-elements) such as `<br />`, `<hr />`, `<img />`, `<input />`, etc. and for [foreign elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/syntax.html#foreign-elements) (such as SVG tags) it designates *a start tag that is marked as self-closing*. It is not a valid syntax for all other tags (such as `<button />` mentioned in your question).

> Then, if the element is one of the void elements, or if the element is a foreign element, then there may be a single U+002F SOLIDUS character (/). This character has no effect on void elements, but on foreign elements it **marks the start tag as self-closing**.

**XML**

According to the [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-eetag) it is called an *empty-element tag*:

> The representation of an empty element is either a start-tag immediately followed by an end-tag, or an **empty-element tag**.

**XHTML**

According to the [XHTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_2) it is called *the minimized tag syntax for empty elements*:

> C.2. Empty Elements
>
> Include a space before the trailing / and > of empty elements, e.g. <br />, <hr /> and <img src="karen.jpg" alt="Karen" />. Also, use **the minimized tag syntax** for empty elements, e.g. <br />, as the alternative syntax <br></br> allowed by XML gives uncertain results in many existing user agents.
>
> C.3. Element **Minimization** and Empty Element Content
>
> Given an empty instance of an element whose content model is not EMPTY (for example, an empty title or paragraph) do not use **the minimized form** (e.g. use <p> </p> and not <p />).

In general if you want to be precise I would recommend using the names as defined in the appropriate standard. Then if people aren't exactly sure what you mean they can look it up in the standard to find out. However if you don't want to use the name in the standard you are free to call it something else if you want. The important thing is that the people who communicate with you can understand you. I don't think anyone would misunderstand you if you used the term 'self-closing tag' for a tag in an XML document even if the standard officially calls it something else.

*Thanks to Alohci for the HTML 5 reference.*

Comment: This is undoubtedly the correct answer, but the important part is that in practice nearly everyone I know calls them "self-closing" tags.

Answer (score 31):

The term is self-closing.

Comment: Maybe you know this, what is the difference between a self-closing tag and a void element (like <br />)? see this wiki (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element)

Comment: Sounds right. One more thing. What would be the term for a tag that needs a closing tag? Regular tag?

Comment: @Tim self-closing tags and "void elements" are the same thing.

Comment: @Emanuil - I suppose I would call it an opening tag or refer to it by its name, i.e, an anchor tag or span tag.  As @Mark Byers suggests, the important thing is that people understand what you're talking about.  I think opening/closing tag and self-closing are pretty widely used.  In conversation I prefer not to be pedantic, but you really ought to make sure that your mark up is legal for whatever document type you're using.  I normally write XHTML for what it's worth.

Answer (score 6):

HTML tags can be of two types. They are

1. **Paired Tags**
2. **Unpaired Tags**

**Paired Tags:**

A tag is said to be a paired tag if the text is placed between a tag and its companion tag. In paired tags, the first tag is referred to as Opening Tag and the second tag is referred to as Closing Tag.

Example:
`<i>`This text is in italics. `</i>`

Note: Here `<i>` is called opening tag. and `</i>` is called closing tag.

**Unpaired Tags**:

An unpaired tag does not have a companion tag. Unpaired tags are also known as Singular or Stand-Alone Tags.

Example : `<br> , <hr>` etc. These tags does not require any companion tag.

Answer (score 2):

Those tags are called "**Standalone Tags**". Standalone tags are having no closing tags in HTML

But in XHTML they have to be self closed by adding forward slash before the closing angular bracket

Answer (score 2):

I've always called them Singleton tags!

Answer (score 2):

**Optional closing tags like `p`, `li`, etc.**

It is also worth mentioning that several other tags besides those mentioned in the question don't need a closing tag: they just close automatically when something specified in the standard appears.

For example:

```
<body>
<p>abc
<p>def
</body>
```

is equivalent to:

```
<body>
<p>abc
</p>
<p>def
</p>
</body>
```

because the `p` closes both at:

- the start of another `p`
- when the parent of the `p` closes

This is specified at 12.1.2.4 "Optional tags" https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#optional-tags but I don't think there's an actual name besides "an element with an optional closing tag".

See also: [P-end-tag (</p>) is not needed in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460993/p-end-tag-p-is-not-needed-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

That is called a self closing tag

Comment: Can you put a source for this?

Answer (score 0):

There are paired and **unpaired tags**.

Unpaired tags are opened and do not have to be closed. They stand alone.

```
<img />, <input /> and <button />
```

Answer (score 0):

I know them as bachelor tags.
e.g. here: http://moodle.cs.huji.ac.il/cs09/file.php/67782/xml-intro.pdf (page 30)

Answer (score 0):

I've called them self-closing, single tags and monotags, I don't know why I haven't adopted a single term though.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen them referred to as singlet (Which is presumably a short form of single-tag)

Answer (score 0):

This sort of Element is an empty element (since it does not contain anything, it just may have attributes). That's the correct way according to the specification, AFAIK. (If the Element is not empty, the Element consists of the opening tag, the closing tag, and the content inbetween.)

Those tags are also called "unpaired", "single", or "bachelor tags". The term "self-closing" I don't like because they don't close themselves any more than other tags, it's still you or your program that puts the "/>" in there.

Answer (score -4):

According to [here](http://perfectionkills.com/tag-is-not-an-element-or-is-it/):

> An element consists of a start tag, content, and an end tag.