# css for parent without class/id

Tags: css, parent-child

i have :

```
<form id="commentform">
    <p class="class1">
    <p class="class2">
    <p>
        <input id="captcha_code"></input>
    </p>
</form>
```

i want to style the "p" which does not have nor id neither class, i want to do it in a way that it does not style the other "p" tags. 
my "p" has a child with id (#captcha_code). i guess, if i can style #captcha_code parent, it will not concern the others... but i do not know how to do it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS selector - element with this child](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220327/css-selector-element-with-this-child)

Answer (score 4):

There is not currently a way to style an element based on whether or not it contains a particular child. The best way I can think to style the `<p>` in your case would be:

```
#commentform p:not([class]){

}
```

Closing your paragraphs [isn't completely necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460993/p-end-tag-p-is-not-needed-in-html), but it's always nicer to read. Additionally, [you shouldn't add a closing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13232170/1612146) for your `input` in HTML:

```
<form id="commentform">
    <p class="class1"></p>
    <p class="class2"></p>
    <p>
        <input id="captcha_code">
    </p>
</form>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/YzE23/)

Comment: Actually, closing the p elements does not always need to be done in HTML5 and in HTML4.01 it was optional, though I always feel safer in doing it.

Comment: Reference: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#optional-tags

Comment: Strangely enough, what you *aren't* allowed to do in HTML is have a closing `</input>` tag.

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock The ironic thing is, the answer I have shared in the question was written by you and I didn't even realise.

Comment: @oGeez: Ha. I forgot I even wrote that answer.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot, it worked !!! Just to know, i closed inout tag for a nicer effect and make it more understandable, i my html, there is no closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
p > input {
  // style for that..
}
```

Using this, the style will be applied to the parent of the `input`.

Fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/WyV7A/

Comment: that will style all the p tags, the OP asked to only style the parent of input with the id captcha_code

Comment: I am sorry, I missed the parent part! @Mauro, check this now :)

Comment: The selector exists, and it means all `input`s that are direct children of a `p` tag.

Comment: My mistake when i say that it doesn't exist i want to say that the parent is not selected here ... "will be applied to the parent of the input" it's wrong

Comment: "the style will be applied to the parent of the `input`." No.

Comment: Thanks Afzaal but your suggestion does not work... look at oGeez' solution, it works very well !

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple, this can't be done.

Unlike the child selector `>`, There is no (and will probably never be) a parent `<`  selector in css.

Have a look at [this article](http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/) to see why.

Comment: You're wrong. Have a look at the fiddle in my answer! :) You'll see that there is a sign for that..

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan Nop sorry, you are using a child selector, not a parent selector :)