# Changing innerhtml value produces a blank line

Tags: javascript, html

I have a toggle link to show or hide a table. This is the code for the link. When this is shown there is no blank line between the link and the table underneath

```
<a id='togglelink' name='togglelink' href='javascript:ToggleTable();' title='Show Inactive EDB Appointments' >
    <p style='text-align:center'>Show Inactive EDB Appointments
</a>
```

When the link is clicked a table is shows and I change the link text

```
link.innerHTML = "<P style='TEXT-ALIGN: center'>Hide Inactive EDB Appointments";
```

After this code is executed a blank line appears between the link and the table underneath

Comment: Maybe it is because your HTML is invalid. You need to close the `<p>` tag.

Comment: Maybe try closing the `<p>` ? That's all I can see wrong since you didn't post all of the javascript

Comment: [You don't need to close the `<p>` tag guys.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460993/p-end-tag-p-is-not-needed-in-html)

Comment: block `<p>` inside inline `<a>` is a really bad practice, also, your `<p>` tag is never closed, then inline css shoul be avoided as soon as possible

Comment: Close the <p> tag.
Also, using href="javascript: [js code] " does not work in some browsers. It's better to use an onclick attribute.

Comment: Show us the code that initializes `link`.

Comment: Testing in FireFox without the closing </p> duplicates the text, and generally messes up the HTML, so I would recommend closing off the <p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close off the paragraph tag within the HTML and the JavaScript.

```html
<a id='togglelink' name='togglelink' href='javascript:ToggleTable();' title='Show Inactive EDB Appointments' >
    <p style='text-align:center'>Show Inactive EDB Appointments</p>
</a>
```

```js
link.innerHTML = "<p style='text-align: center'>Hide Inactive EDB Appointments</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the `<p>` tag.

`link.innerHTML = "<p style='text-align: center'>Hide Inactive EDB Appointments</p>";`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using href="javascript: [some code]", which does not work in all browsers, you should use an onclick attribute as below and demo'd in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sqsinger/kwjmfgku/)

```
<a id='togglelink' name='togglelink' href='#' title='Show Inactive EDB Appointments' onclick="ToggleTable();">
     <p style='text-align:center'>Show Inactive EDB Appointments
     </p><!-- Added in closing tag -->
</a>
```

### Notes:

1. I made sure to close the `<p>` tag, though this was not the problem.
2. I've provided an example ToggleTable() function that guesses at how you initialize `var link`. I'd recommend `document.getElementById('togglelink')` or `$('#togglelink')` if using jQuery.
3. An alternative to the onclick attribute, as commented in [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sqsinger/kwjmfgku/), is an event listener. Example below, if using jQuery:

```
function ToggleTable() {
    var link = document.getElementById("togglelink");
    link.innerHTML = "<P style='TEXT-ALIGN: center'>Hide Inactive EDB Appointments</p>";
}

$(document).on("click tap","#togglelink",function() {
    ToggleTable();
});
```