# Javadoc closing tags

Tags: java, javadoc

Reading [Oracle's Javadoc Documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#examples), I noticed that the author did not close the `<p>` tag.

```
/**
 * The method used for creating the tree. Any structural 
 * modifications to the display of the Jtree should be done 
 * by overriding this method.
 * <p>
 * This method adds an anonymous TreeSelectionListener to 
 * the returned JTree.  Upon receiving TreeSelectionEvents, 
 * this listener calls refresh with the selected node as a 
 * parameter. 
 */
public JTree makeTree(AreaInfo ai){
}
```

The documentation states:

> If you have more than one paragraph in the doc comment, separate the paragraphs with a `<p>` paragraph tag, as shown.

In Eclipse, the Javadoc is formatted correctly, but just because it works, does it mean it's "correct"?

Comment: I think it's accepted in the Java community that your javadoc doc tags don't have to be syntactically correct HTML. Just de facto, there is only one place where I have seen someone bother to put `</p>` in their javadoc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460993/p-end-tag-p-is-not-needed-in-html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. Quote from [the specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.1):

> Some HTML element types allow authors to omit end tags (e.g., the P and LI element types)

Comment: Since you beat me to the answer, I'll add the the p tag also specifies that it may omit its closing tag in some circumstances.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html `A p element’s end tag may be omitted if the p element is immediately followed by an address, article, aside, blockquote, dir, div, dl, fieldset, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hr, menu, nav, ol, p, pre, section, table, or ul element, or if there is no more content in the parent element and the parent element is not an a element.`

Comment: And there's the [JEP 224](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/224) about adding HTML5 support to javadoc.

Comment: JEP 224 has been delivered and is available in Java ≥9.