# Not correct height of flex child box which contains 100% width image in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I use [Chris' Coyer approach](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/#comment-1601783) to make a footer been sticky at the bottom of page.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content-box">
    <div class="image-box">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIQ2T.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-box">Bottom</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh; /* Avoid the IE 10-11 `min-height` bug. */
}
.bottom-box {
  flex-shrink: 0; /* Prevent Chrome, Opera, and Safari from letting these items shrink to smaller than their content's default minimum size. */  
  background: #069;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 3;
}
.content-box {
  flex: 1 0 auto; /* Prevent Chrome, Opera, and Safari from letting these items shrink to smaller than their content's default minimum size. */
}
.image-box img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

It worked fine. Until I've faced the problem in Internet Explorer 11. If I put a big image to the inner box and resize it using `max-width: 100%` then the parent box takes a height of original image before resizing.

**Actual:**
Parent box takes a height of original image before resizing. It works so in IE11.

[image: There is scroll]

**Expected:**

Parent box takes a height of the image after resizing. It works so in Chrome, Firefox, Safari.
[image: No scroll]

**JSFIDDLE**:
To have better understanding the problem you can take a look at code and example here: https://jsfiddle.net/v9ocv7b6/31/

Does anybody have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Is that what you need: http://codepen.io/themeler/pen/vgMjow ?

Comment: @PrzemysławMelnarowicz unfortunately no :(

Answer (score 0):

You tried use prefix -ms- for IE?

```
http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox
```

Comment: Does IE11 require vendor prefix to support flexbox? No, it doesn't :)

Comment: But it seems IE11 has a great deal of bugs with flex: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37905749/flexbox-not-working-in-internet-explorer-11

Comment: @fauxserious yes, unfortunately it has many bugs but this one kind of new. With vendor prefixes I got the same result.

Comment: @grinmax I know about "min-height issue" in IE that's why there is `height` property used...