# flexbox with 5 boxes

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to achieve the following layout using flexbox
[image: flex]

I've tried this in grid it's working as expected. but it's not working in IE. so i thought of switching to flexbox so below are my versions of both grid and flex.

grid code is as follows:

```css
 //this is with grid css
.grid_container {
  width: 65%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1.5rem;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  max-width: 1100px;
  display: -ms-grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;             
  -ms-grid-row-gap:1.5rem;
  -ms-grid-column-gap:1.5rem;
}
//this is using grid css
.box-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  }
 
//inside image css
.box-item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.box-text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 12px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid_container">
 <div class="box-item">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/350x275/000/fff" />
  <div class="box-text">
   dummy text
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box-item">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/350x275/000/fff" />
  <div class="box-text">
   dummy text
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box-item">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/350x275/000/fff" />
  <div class="box-text">
   dummy text
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box-item">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/350x275/000/fff" />
  <div class="box-text">
   dummy text
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box-item">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/350x275/000/fff" />
  <div class="box-text">
   dummy text
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to do the same thing in flexbox but i was not able to achieve it: the css code looks as follows:

```css
//the same class using flex property
.grid_container{
    margin: 10px auto;
    max-width: 1100px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-flow: wrap;
}

//this is with flex
.box-item {
  width: 33%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 33%; 
  position: relative;
}

//inside image css
.box-item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.box-text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 12px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
}

//trying to add responsiveness
@media only screen and (max-width: 780px) {
.box-item {
  width: 45%;
}
}
```

Comment: css-grid is only partially supported in IE 11 and 13.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flexbox not working in Internet Explorer 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37905749/flexbox-not-working-in-internet-explorer-11)

Comment: hi @tacoshy, i've lately realized it so now i want to achieve the samething with flexbox. any idea how can i achieve the same layout showed in image with flex

Answer (score 0):

For your **main container**:

```
.main-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Then your **item**:

```
.item {
    flex-basis: 30%;
}
```

Comment: Please explain here _what_ and _why_ you changed.

Comment: The question was how to position 5 boxes inside a flex container in a specific way, in my answer I show the code of how to do it, I changed nothing, just gave an example.

Comment: Still, you could explain what each part of it does, so others can learn from. Now it's just a copy and paste answer.

Comment: I think its pretty much self explanatory, add a `basis` attribute to the flex item and wrap the main container with `flex-wrap`

Comment: It's clear for *you*, but if someone searches for the same question, ends up here and sees this, it might be that he/she needs more context. The quality of your answer is way higher with explanations.

Comment: If someone wants an easy exit they have it here, if they want to know what exactly the attributes do they can easily google them and find out, I don't think its necessary to explain what `flex-wrap` or `flex-basis` does

Answer (score 0):

for the flex version, just use

```
align-content: flex-start;
```

Comment: that answer was already given (and in a lot more helpful way!)

Comment: @jasie As far as I can tell, this was the first answer to mention `flex-start`, though I agree more explanation would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

First, the comments here are single line comments, you should always use multi line comments to comment text in CSS. I removed all comments and then ran your code, it worked properly, because there is no `//` comments in CSS, there is only one comment style in CSS is `/* text */`. Adding `//` comments only breaks the stylesheet. Then your code will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.grid_container {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      column-gap: 20px;
      row-gap: 20px;
     
    }

    .grid_container > .box-item {
        align-content: flex-start;
       
        width: calc(33.33% - 40px);
    }
   .box-item img { 
       width:100%;
    }

@media(max-width:767px){
  .grid_container > .box-item { 
    width:100%; 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid_container">
     <div class="box-item">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/350x275/000/fff" />
      <div class="box-text">
       dummy text
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="box-item">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/350x275/000/fff" />
      <div class="box-text">
       dummy text
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="box-item">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/350x275/000/fff" />
      <div class="box-text">
       dummy text
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="box-item">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/350x275/000/fff" />
      <div class="box-text">
       dummy text
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="box-item">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/350x275/000/fff" />
      <div class="box-text">
       dummy text
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```