# Template parse errors: Unexpected closing tag "p"

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to format XML file in Angular. I tried this:

```
<div class="element-box">
  <div class="details-wrapper">
    <p><b class="label">Raw Request</b>
      <pre>
        {{apiattempt.raw_request | xmlBeautyfier }}
      </pre>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR in : Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "p". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("
        {{apiattempt.raw_request | xmlBeautyfier }}
      </pre>
    [ERROR ->]</p>
    <p><b class="label">Raw Response</b>{{apiattempt.raw_response | xmlBeautyfier }}</p>
  </div"):
```

Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: The p tag can be implicitly closed by the use of other tags; see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460993/p-end-tag-p-is-not-needed-in-html) question

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags

Comment: Good question - I didn’t know that.

Answer (score 12):

The `<pre>` tag is a block level element. When that is placed inside the `<p>...</p>` it will act like a `</p>` causing it to close and throwing an error when it gets to your `</p>`. Either close the `<p>` before your `<pre>` or wrap the `pre` in a different element if you want it wrapped.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p

Comment: Is there any work around the end result is not formatted well.

Comment: How do you want it formatted? <pre></pre> is used to make the text appear as is.

Comment: Yes, pre></pre> is used to make the text inside formatted

Answer (score 4):

Refer to: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags

In HTML: p tag is implicity closed with next element. So

- the first p tag starts p and ends with b or pre tag. (it is implicitly closed).
- then then the parser finds /p closing tag for which it doesnt see the preceding p tag. (the first one was implicitly closed).

Solutions (from best the worst):

- dont use p when you do more tricky stuff. You have pre tag so you should consider changing your original p with div or span
- OR drop /p (ok idea)
- OR add p in the front of /p. (bad idea to have there  /p  ..)

Possible solution to investigate:
- XHTML requires explicit closing p tag. You can try to use XHTML and let us know if it works. Note: this is a bit of an overkill to your problem... bit always good to learn ;-)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

From [html.com](https://html.com/tags/p/):

> The closing `<p>` tag is optional and is implied by the opening tag of the next HTML element encountered in an HTML document after an opening `<p>` tag.

Comment: remove the closing </p> tag? does that generate any exceptions?