# What is "<p><p a>" in HTML?

Tags: html, css

What is the first line of code in the example below

```
<p><p a>
```

I saw a youtuber writing the below code and it displayed a design in cssbattle challenge.I also tried it,it works.But I never saw it on any HTML tutorials before and I searched it on Google but it was showing resuts for paragraphs tags only which I already know.[here is the link for the youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6uSE1KaBSaI&ab_channel=CodeFy).

```
<p><p a>
<style>
  body{
    background:#E6D9AC;
  }
  p{
    width:91px;
    height:30px;
    padding:30px 0;
    border:30px solid #BD6C27;
    border-right:none;
    background:#BD6C27;
    position:absolute;
    top:44;
    left:125;
    background-clip:content-box;
  }
  [a]{
    background:#8F2D2B;
    border-color:#8F2D2B;
    left:155px;
    top:74px;
    rotate:-180deg;
    background-clip:content-box;
  }
</style>
```

I know about `<p></p>` tags but this `<p><p a>` tag, I didn't see it in HTML before. Do you know what it is called?

Comment: Its just a `p` tag with an attribute `a`.

Answer (score 1):

`<p>` is opening of a paragraph tag/element. `<p a>` is just another opening of paragraph tag/element with an attribute `a`. As you can see from the video, person selects elements with attribute `a` using `[a]`. It's used to just to differ paragraph elements. But this HTML is not valid since paragraph elements dont have a closing `</p>` tag.

Comment: Just a note, in HTML (not XHTML), paragraph tags don't technically need a closing tag and is valid. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8461004/978005

Comment: Omitting the `p` close tag is perfectly valid. But the `a`  attribute is not.