# Why is the font awesome showing up three times?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, css-grid

```
<div class="Contact-form">
        <div id= "form-area" class="sadaka-form">
            <h2>CONTACT FORM</h2>
            <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name*">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail*" >
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message*" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            <button class= "form-control">Send message</button>
        </div>
        <div id= "contact-area" class="sadaka-contacts">
            <h3>SADAKA CONTACTS</h3>
            <p>Sadaka ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut at eros rutrum turpis viverra elementum semper quis ex. Donec lorem nulla .</p>
            <ul>
                <li><span><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></span></li>
                <li><span><i class="fa fa-phone"></span></li>
                <li><span><i class="fa fa-envelope"></span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

my problem is that the font awesome icon is showing up three times. i dont know where am i doing wrong ? i have included the link to the error screenshot as well.

Here is the image [image]

Comment: `<i>` not close?

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^ this

Comment: You forgot to add closing of  <i> tag

Comment: You don't need to wrap your <i> tags in <span> tags.  That's just extra overhead.

Comment: well i need to do some styling. let me see if i need them anyways . thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way to use FontAwesome icons is: `<i class="fas fa-map-marker"></i>` (look at the final `</i>` tag).

In your case:

```
<li><span><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></span></li>
<li><span><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span></li>
<li><span><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `i` tag should be closed.

```
<ul>
    <li><span><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></span></li>
    <li><span><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span></li>
    <li><span><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span></li>
</ul>
```

The `i` tag is **not** an [empty html](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_elements.asp) tag nor a [solidus tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741896/what-do-you-call-tags-that-need-no-ending-tag)  and hence needs a closing tag

Comment: Argh... now we have also a `span` not well closed... (^_^;)

Comment: hehe..side effects of trying to answer quick in such a competitive stackoverflow userbase

Comment: ahahahah... I understand well what you mean. Here they are all very fast ;)